# T-SQL to retrieve history data from table/log_table by RelevanceDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

```
1) TBL (ID, Data, LastUpdated, DateCreated)
2) TBL_LOG(Log_ID, LogCreateDate, ID, Data, LastUpdated, DateCreated)
```

`TBL` used to store current data and `TBL_LOG` used to store every change of data in `TBL` (using update trigger, the deleted record from `TBL` copied to `TBL_LOG`).

Now I need to retrieve the data by relevance date.
How I can write the table valued function (or other alternative) that will return the data depending on `RelevanceDate`.

I understand the logic, but I can't find a good way to write it in SQL...
The logic looks like:

```
@RelevanceDate = '2011-03-01'
IF TBL.LastUpdated <= @RelevanceDate THEN return data from TBL
ELSE IF Exists data in TBL_LOG where TBL_LOG.LastUpdated <= @RelevanceDate 
    THEN return most resent data from TBL_LOG where TBL_LOG.LastUpdated <= @RelevanceDate
ELSE IF Exists data in TBL_LOG where TBL_LOG.LastUpdated > @RelevanceDate 
    THEN return the oldest data from TBL_LOG.LastUpdated > @RelevanceDate
ELSE return data from TBL
```

This function should return data using the logic above, for all records in `TBL`.

In short words, for each row in TBL i need data that was on "RelevanceDate".

Comment: Your two `ELSE IF` blocks have the same condition : `Exists data in TBL_LOG where TBL_LOG.LastUpdated < @RelevanceDate `

Comment: store everything in the TBL_LOG and then you only need to query TBL_LOG.  Basically make a trigger insert into TBL_LOG on INSERT and UPDATE of TBL.  If you add an "Action" column you can even store deletes.  as for your query, I'm not sure what you are after, possibly explain in english, and not in your your code fragment what you are after.  You probably need to UNION a TBL table query with a query of TBL_LOG.

Comment: As a starting point, I used UNION ALL for TBL and TBL_LOG to have single result set to select from. Now how i can select the record with the data that was on "RelevanceDate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of my investigation, i ended up with something like folowing:

```
DECLARE @RelevanceDate DATETIME
SET @RelevanceDate = '2012-03-01'

SELECT 
        MainData.ID, MainData.Data, MainData.LastUpdated, MainData.DateCreated
FROM   (
           SELECT 
                  *
                  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AllData.ID, AllData.RowNum ORDER BY AllData.LastUpdated) AS MainRowNumber
           FROM   (
                      --Current Data
                      SELECT 
                             NULL LogID
                            ,NULL LogCreateDate
                            ,*
                            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC) AS RowNum
                      FROM   TBL
                      WHERE  (lastupdate<=@RelevanceDate)

                      UNION

                      --History Data
                      SELECT  
                            *
                            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LastUpdated) AS RowNum
                      FROM   TBL_LOG
                      WHERE  lastupdate>@RelevanceDate
                  ) AllData WHERE AllData.RowNum=1
       ) MainData
WHERE  MainData.MainRowNumber = 1
```

If someone have a suggestion how it can be done in better way, i will glad to see it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use NESTED CASE Statements in your select, roughly along these lines:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN TBL.LastUpdated <= @RelevanceDate  THEN TBL.data ELSE
        CASE WHEN TBL_LOG.LastUpdated < @RelevanceDate AND NOT TBL_LOG.Data IS NULL THEN 
             TBL_LOG.Data
        ELSE
             ...
        END
    END AS Data
FROM TBL TBL
LEFT JOIN TBL_LOG TBL_LOG
ON TBL.ID = TBL_LOG.ID
```

Comment: This method will work, but I can't use it since it will be very hard to maintain in...for each field in TBL i will need to create the nested cases. Anyway thank you !